# How to get the project root directory in a Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

I use Jenkins `v2.222.1` and created a simple pipeline for a project. For the deployment I want to set the release/tag name manually. So the plan, how I want it working is:

- I change the release name/number in a defined file, e.g. `/root/of/my/project/release.txt`.
- I start deployment by clicking <kbd>Build Now</kbd>
- Jenkins reads the release name/number from the file.
- Jenkins checks out the appropriate tag (and creates and `push`es the according branch).

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'dev'
    }
    stages {
        stage('build') {
            environment {
                APP_VERSION = sh (
                    script: 'eval "cat $REMOTE_ROOT_DIRECTORY/release.txt"', returnStdout: true
                )
            }
            steps {
                sh 'git fetch --all --tags'
                sh 'git checkout ${APP_VERSION} -b v${APP_VERSION}'
                ...
            }
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Since I haven't found out, how to get the *remote root directory* path, I use a workaround: The `$WORKSPACE` is placed in the folder `/workspace/$project_name` (where the `$project_name` is the project name / title defined in Jenkins). So I just use this knowledge and define the path for `cat` as `../../release.txt`. It works, but is a bit dirty because of the hard-coded path in the `Jenkinsfile`.

**How to get / retrieve the *project root directory* dynamically in a Jenkins pipeline?**

Comment: Not sure what exactly you meant by _remote_ directory path but did you try this: `cat $WORKSPACE/release.txt`?